# Why wont Bootstrap Carousel Sliders work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I made run my carousel the  images rotate automatically  after five seconds but when I click the right and left sliders it wont slide, also nothing happens when I scroll down to click the indicators the screen just scrolls up and down like a lag, any suggestions.

My Code is:

```
        <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="home-carousel">

            <!--To Create Indicators-->

            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li class="active" data-target="#home-carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                <li class="active" data-target="#home-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li class="active" data-target="#home-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li class="active" data-target="#home-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper For Slides-->

            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="Images/Chilli.jpg">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>A Title</h3>
                        <p>A Caption</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="Images/Dough.jpg">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>A Title</h3>
                        <p>A Caption</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="Images/jars.jpg">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>A Title</h3>
                        <p>A Caption</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="Images/Breakfast.jpg">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>A Title</h3>
                        <p>A Caption</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Left and Right Sliders-->

            <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"><span class="sr-only">PREVIOUS</span></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">NEXT</span></a>
        </div>
```

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

remove `class="active"` from rest of the slides **but first** and you should be through , so essentially it should read

```
 <li class="active" data-target="#home-carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                <li  data-target="#home-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#home-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li  data-target="#home-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have forget to link `jQuery` and bootstrap library 
[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dkhLxvmz/1/)

And use active for one li only

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li class="active" data-target="#home-carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                <li class="" data-target="#home-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li class="" data-target="#home-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li class="" data-target="#home-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, my own carousel buttons are working and I can see a couple of obvious differences between your code and my code (below).  I'm referring the button back to the carousel and I've got a defined roll of "button".  Hope that helps.

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```